# Does a SQL JOIN's ON imply WHERE?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

When joining a very large table to a small table, I try to be as specific as possible in my join query. Am I going overboard, however?

Let's say I have SmallTable with one column and just three values: "Peter", "Paul", and "Mary". I'll end up joining a bunch of huge tables to this. Should I put a WHERE statement in my join in order to narrow the join's select statement? Or does a join imply the where condition?

```
SELECT
  Username,
  click.TotalClicks,
  otherjoin.SneezePercent,
  anotherjoin.Coats
FROM
  SmallTable
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    Person,
    SUM(Clicks) AS TotalClicks
  FROM
    HugeTable
  WHERE
    Person LIKE 'Peter' OR Person LIKE 'Paul' OR Person LIKE 'Mary'
) click
ON click.Person = Username
LEFT JOIN (
...
```

Comment: which is it? ssms or mySql? And... the query optimiser decides how the query will be executed, but as you say, elinimating rows as early as possible is usually the right way.

Comment: SSMS and TSQL conflict with MySQL. Please don't tag spam. Use only the tags that are actually relevant to your question.. Do not randomly add others that just seem similar. Tags have relevance and meaning here. Thanks.

Comment: Have you examined the actual execution plan for various queries to see how the query optimizer is helping you?

Comment: Sorry, all! I removed the mysql tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the version you currently have is the optimal one, because your `WHERE` restriction will save the database from aggregating over names whose results you ultimately will be discarding anyway in the join, in the outer query.  Your current use of `LIKE` might preclude an index, but the database also might be able to use an index in that `WHERE` clause, for even better performance.

The alternative to this, namely relying on the join with the small table, would filter out names you don't want, but by then the aggregation would have already been done on the entire large table.

Comment: So the real question, then, is which is applied first, the ON or the WHERE?

Comment: @Anthony The entire subquery has to evaluate before the join can happen, AFAIK, so the `WHERE` in the subquery should evaluate before the join does.  Actually, the `WHERE` in the subquery is one of the first things which will evaluate in the subquery.